# Show that $||f||_p = \Big(\int_{(0, 1)} | \sum_{n > 0} n \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]}|^p d\lambda \Big)^{1/p} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^p}{2^n}$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm required to show that
$$||f||_p = \Big(\int_{(0, 1)} \Big| \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]} \Big|^p d\lambda \Big)^{1/p} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^p}{2^n}$$
where $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]}$.

I'm pretending to show that $f \in L^p(\lambda)$, for every $p \in (0, +\infty)$ and I know that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^p}{2^n} < + \infty$ and

$$\int_{(0,1)} |f|^p d\lambda = ||f||_p^p$$

So, if I prove the required equality, $||f||_p^p < + \infty$ and therefore, $f \in L^p(\lambda)$.

Here $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure and $X = (0, 1)$.

But I couldn't make much progress in the proof of the equality. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1. It is direct to show that $f \in L^1(\lambda)$ and by some theorem, it is also direct to show that $f \in L^p(\lambda)$, for every $p \in (0, 1)$. So if required, one can suppose that $p > 1$.

Comment: Are you missing a $\sqrt[p]{\cdot}$ on the discrete summations? Note that because the indicators are disjoint you can take the summation outside the integral (with a little justification, of course).

Comment: @copper.hat Actually, I'm trying to figure it out. We know that $$\int_{(0,1)} |f|^p d\lambda = \int_{(0,1)} \Big( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]} \Big)^p d\lambda$$ Why can I take the sum outside the integral? I mean, why does it holds for the pow $p$?

Comment: Read my comment carefully, in particular the disjoint part.

Comment: @copper.hat So basically I should prove that $$\Big( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]} \Big)^p = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^p \cdot 1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]}$$ right? Of course, using the disjoint part. Thus, by the Monotone Converge Theorem, were are done. If yes, we conclude that $$\int |f|^p = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^p}{2^n}$$ meaning that, yes I was missing an $\sqrt[p]{\cdot}$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, albeit the first part is straightforward if you just evaluate it at a particular point.